# How to get value and label of selected option onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

How can I get label and value of select field onChange event?

For example, when the user selects the 'A' option, I need to retrieve the value
`taskId=1`
and the label
`taskLabel=A`.

```
const [taskId, setTaskId] = useState()
const [tasklabel, setTaskLabel] = useState()

<ProFormSelect
   onChange={(value) => {setTaskId(value)}}
   name="task"
   label="Task"
   options={[
     {
       value: "1",
       label: "A",
      },
      {
        value: "2",
        label: "B",
       },
     ]}
 />
```

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: `onChange={(value, secondparam)` try logging the second param it should give the selected option

Answer (score 2):

If the component you're using doesn't support returning both label and value, you can modify the onChange function to search for the label based on the value.

```
const options = [
  { value: "1", label: "A" },
  { value: "2", label: "B" },
];

const handleChange = (value: string) => {
  setTaskId(value);
  
  const selectedOption = options.find((option) => option.value === value);
  
  if (selectedOption) {
    setTaskLabel(selectedOption.label);
  }
};

<ProFormSelect
  onChange={handleChange}
  name="task"
  label="Task"
  options={options}
/>;
```